# Python Series.mean() Vs List.mean() , getting different responses

Tags: python, list, series

Here is a sample data i have in excel

---

Salary in Rs.

---

12598
25031
25187
25226
25232
37512
37592
50145
50274
62630
62768
75392
87654

---

And i am trying to read the data using the pandas ExcelFile and parse the sheet after wards.

I am trying to get the mean of the above values  through

```
ExcelValue=pandas.ExcelFile("stats.xlsx")
Sheet1=ExcelValue.parse("sheet1")

var1=Sheet1["Salary in Rs."]
var2=var1.tolist()
mean1=statistics.mean(var1) # getting mean as 44403.153846153844
mean2=statistics.mean(var2)  # getting mean as 44403
```

both are returning different values , am not understaing that .can you please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though the integer values passed to `statistics.mean` for your series are resulting in your output value being truncated as an integer. There are two solutions:

1. You force the series to contain floats - `var1 = Sheet1["Salary in Rs."].astype(float)`
2. You ignore `statistics` entirely and use the `mean` method  built into the `pandas` `Series` object - `var1.mean()`